# Why can't I change the text color of a UILabel in my XIB file?

Tags: uilabel, interface-builder, xib, textcolor

I have been trying to change the text color of a UILabel element in my XIB file but I am unable to. If I change it to white in IB it still renders as black when I run the app.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the cell's textLabel property instead of my own custom class on the cell.